# How to generate the largest number from an input array using Python?

Tags: python, arrays

For example the input is [8, 23, 7, 9] --> the output is 98723

Input [865, 1038, 2] --> output 86521038

Comment: Please make some effort to solving the problem yourself, and showing wgere you got stuck, rather than asking for a complete solution.

Comment: Sort them as *strings* in descending order (`str()`)

Comment: @tevemadar: Not quite. That gives the wrong result for inputs like `[5, 54]`.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by the first digit of each number in descending order and concatenate the sorted numbers.

```
array = [865, 1038, 2]
largest = int(''.join(sorted({str(n): int(str(n)[0]) for n in array}, reverse=True)))
print(largest)
```

**Output:**
`86521038`

Answer (score 0):

Converting the list of integers to strings and then sorting them is close to the correct answer, and works for the examples in the question. However, as [user2357112-supports-monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) pointed out, this fails for cases where one number is the prefix of another number, since the longer number is always put first: e.g. `[5, 54]` becomes `545` not `554`. To fix this, we can make a custom comparator that checks for these prefix cases and accounts for them by removing the prefix from the longer number: in `[5, 54]`, the `4` is less than `5`, so `5` comes before `54`, but in `[5, 56]`, `6` is greater than `5` so `56` comes before `5`.

In a slightly more complicated example, `[121, 12]`:

- first the prefix (`12`) is removed from `121` to make `1`, so now we are comparing `1` and `12`
- `1` is a prefix of `12`, so now we are comparing `1` and `2`
- `2` is greater so comes first
- so `12` comes before `121`, making the answer `12121` not `12112`

Here is some code that implements this:

```
def largest_combination(input_list):
    strings = [str(x) for x in input_list]

    def compare(a: str, b: str):
        if a == b:  # test for equality first, since every string starts with itself
            return 0
        if a.startswith(b):  # if b is a prefix of a, discard the prefix from a and try comparing again
            return compare(a[len(b):], b)
        elif b.startswith(a):  # symmetric case
            return -compare(b, a)
        elif a < b:  # otherwise compare like a normal string
            return -1
        else:
            return 1

    # sort and join together
    combined = ''.join(sorted(strings, key=cmp_to_key(compare), reverse=True))
    # convert to int
    return int(combined)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(largest_combination([8, 23, 7, 9]) == 98723)
    print(largest_combination([865, 1038, 2]) == 86521038)
    print(largest_combination([5, 56]) == 565)
    print(largest_combination([5, 54]) == 554)
    print(largest_combination([5, 556]) == 5565)
    print(largest_combination([5, 554]) == 5554)
    print(largest_combination([12121, 12]) == 1212121)
    print(largest_combination([21, 21212]) == 2121221)
```

Edit: fixed the problem kindly pointed out by @tevemadar

Comment: `[5, 556]` and `[5, 554]` can trick it.

Comment: @tevemadar good point - fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I think when comparing sequences of different length, you may repeat the shorter one to deal with possible prefix-cases pointed out in a comment and in @Oli's answer. While this approach feels somewhat fishy, it works at the first look at least. When they are not prefixes of each other, the "hack" doesn't do anything, as the "normal" part of the comparison decides. However when there is a prefix case, it seems to be necessary.

Test cases `5, 556` (should result in `5565`) and `5, 554` (which should result in `5554`) can't be decided by looking at the prefix (`5` vs `5`56/4), looking at the repeat of the prefix (5`5` vs 5`5`6/4), but it needs looking at an imagined 3rd copy of the prefix (55`5` vs 55`6/4`) even if we don't actually have that many repeats.
I'm not sure what's happening, but somehow it works for these handful of tests.

Piggybacking Oli's framework, and added the two new test cases:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def largest_combination(input_list):
    strings = [str(x) for x in input_list]

    def compare(a: str, b: str):
        complen = max(len(a), len(b))
        while len(a) < complen:
            a += a
        a = a[:complen]
        while len(b) < complen:
            b += b
        b = b[:complen]
        return int(a) - int(b)

    # sort and join together
    combined = ''.join(sorted(strings, key=cmp_to_key(compare), reverse=True))
    # convert to int
    return int(combined)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(largest_combination([8, 23, 7, 9]) == 98723)
    print(largest_combination([865, 1038, 2]) == 86521038)
    print(largest_combination([5, 56]) == 565)
    print(largest_combination([5, 54]) == 554)
    print(largest_combination([5, 556]) == 5565)
    print(largest_combination([5, 554]) == 5554)
```

Comment: `[12121,12]` can trick it.